# Getting strange result while trying to create UIButton with image and text

Tags: ios, swift, image, text, uibutton

I am trying to create an `UIButton` with custom `UIButtonType` configured with a left aligned image and a centred text. However every example I can find (there is a lot) does not work and creates some strange result. 
The code I using:

```
let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(StartController.button), for: .touchUpInside)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "IMG_0124"), for: .normal)
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0)
button.setTitle("Back", for: .normal)
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 0)
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
```

I am getting this in the debugger:

```
(lldb) po button.imageView?.frame
▿ Optional<CGRect>
  ▿ some : (10.0, 0.0, 90.0, 100.0)
    ▿ origin : (10.0, 0.0)
      - x : 10.0
      - y : 0.0
    ▿ size : (90.0, 100.0)
      - width : 90.0
      - height : 100.0


(lldb) po button.titleLabel?.frame
▿ Optional<CGRect>
  ▿ some : (100.0, 50.0, 2368.0, 0.0)
    ▿ origin : (100.0, 50.0)
      - x : 100.0
      - y : 50.0
    ▿ size : (2368.0, 0.0)
      - width : 2368.0
      - height : 0.0
```

I am unable to set the the frame via `button.imageView?.frame`.

This is what I want to get:
[image]

This is what I get:
[image]

The button is not part of a UINavigationController. It's a subview of a simple UIView.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: There could be several things wrong, but until you tell us two things it's hard to tell. (1) What are you expecting to see? Also, is this supposed to be part of a UINavigationBar? I' asking because of the "Back" title. (2) What are you seeing? Anything? Help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

**swift 3.**
Try this

```
button.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
button.titleLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
button.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)`
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
```

Comment: Sorry, that does not help